# Tomcat7 on digital ocean, started but unaccessible from browser

Tags: java, web, tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04, digital-ocean

I just installed tomcat7 on Digital Ocean (ubuntu 12) through this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-on-ubuntu-12-04 , everything seems like installed correctly, tomcat7 already started, but I don't know why it's not working and not accessible from browser using myipaddress:8080.
any help greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: I tried to access using curl  on terminal (using ssh remote terminal) locally then it's just work, but when I tried to access it from browser it's not gives me any respond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, use this to allow remote access to tomcat7 on port 8080 :

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're running a Linux distribution (e.g. CentOS) that by default blocks 8080 (or more ports) in firewall rules. You can verify this by running `iptables-save` and see if there're rules blocking any port.

If that's the case run

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`

to unblock 8080.

Comment: OK now I see you've figured it out ;)